# ask user to get pointer coordinate in applescript

Tags: click, applescript, coordinate

I need to ask my user to click somewhere in his screen to get the coordinate of where he click.

Is it possible to do this in applescript ?

Thanks

Dam

Answer (score 1):

No. But I wrote a tool called [MouseTools](http://www.hamsoftengineering.com/codeSharing/MouseTools/MouseTools.html). It can help you get mouse coordinates.